# Was bedeuten die bayerischen oder österreichischen Präpositionen "aufi" und "obi"?

Tags: regional, bavarian, austrian

Ich habe zwar einige Jahre in Niederbayern gewohnt, bin bezüglich dieser Präpositionen nie richtig sattelfest geworden.

Außerdem wissen die Einheimischen in diesen Fällen sehr wohl, dass sie die **Zugereisten** hier köstlich verwirren können.

Hier ein Beispiel aus [Östereich](http://diepresse.com/home/spectrum/zeichenderzeit/606312/Do-obi-und-durt-aufi)

Comment: Nein, weiß ich nicht, für mich ist es nicht nachvollziehbar, wie man die Bedeutung "aufi" als Präposition nicht richtig erraten kann. Die Unterstellung weise ich mit aller Deutlichkeit zurück.

Comment: Inzwischen habe ich noch folgende ziemlich umfangreiche Quelle gefunden: [www.bayrisch-lernen.de](http://www.bayrisch-lernen.de/). Dort unter Grammatik findet man das auch ziemlich ausführlich.

Comment: Sollte man hier „bayerisch oder österreichisch“ durch „bairisch“ ersetzen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Das Suffix *-i* im Bairischen entspricht dem Präfix „hin-“ im Hochdeutschen. Es handelt sich dabei um eine Bewegung vom Standpunkt des Sprechers weg:

- Ich gehe hinauf = I geh auffi
- Ich gehe hinaus = I geh aussi
- Ich gehe hinunter = I geh obi
- Ich gehe hinein = I geh eini
- Ich gehe nach vorne (Sprecher steht hinter dem Angesprochenen) = I geh firi

Das Suffix *-a* im Bairischen entspricht dem Präfix „her-“ im Hochdeutschen. Es handelt sich dabei um eine Bewegung zum Standpunkt des Sprechers hin:

- Ich gehe herauf = I geh auffa
- Ich gehe heraus = I geh aussa
- Ich gehe herunter = I geh oba
- Ich gehe herein = I geh eina
- Ich gehe nach vorne (Sprecher steht vor dem Angesprochenen) = I geh fira

Im Bairischen werden üblicherweise die Suffixe verwendet. Die Präfixe können verwendet werden, um Richtung der Bewegung zu betonen: *I geh hínaus* könnte etwa nach einem Streit verwendet werden, um zu betonen, dass der Sprecher nicht mehr im Haus ist.

Im Oberbairischen wird teilweise das Präfix allgemein verwendet, allerdings verkürzt auf *n-* für „hin-“ und *r-* für „her-“: *I geh naus* anstellte von *I geh aussi*; *I geh raus* anstelle von *I geh heraus*. Möglicherweise kann dies allerdings durch eine Beeinflussung durch das Hochdeutsche erklärt werden.

Ich habe außerdem beobachtet, dass bei vielen Sprechern von anderen Dialekten das „r-“ als generisches Präfix für alle lokativischen Angaben verwendet wird – d. h., sowohl „heraus“ als auch „hinaus“ fallen in „raus“ zusammen. Dies könnte erklären, dass Zugereiste Probleme mit dem Präpositionen haben. Sofern die Sprecher aber die Präfixe „hin-“ und „her-“ unterscheiden können, sollten die Suffixe eigentlich zu meistern sein.

Comment: Gerade die "-i"/"-a" unterscheidung gefällt mir persönlich sehr: sehr kompakt aber verwirrend, wenn man den genauen Unterschied nicht kennt ;-)

Comment: Jetzt wird's echt kompliziert: Ich (Oberbayer in der Oberpfalz) kenne "-i" für die Bewegung *vom Sprecher weg* und "-a" für die Bewegung *zum Sprecher hin* - aber vielleicht liegt da in der Beschreibung nur eine Verwechslung vor? (vielleicht andere Beispiele? "I geh auffa" etc. funktioniert bei uns zumindest nicht, weil der Satz impliziert, dass der Sprecher bereits oben ist auff*a*, und jetzt nochmal rauf geht). Oder?

Comment: @Mac Stimmt - eigentlich wollte ich "Ziel des Sprechakts" sagen, weil ja nicht immer der Sprecher gemeint ist. Warum ich dann "Zuhörer" draus gemacht habe, ist mir jetzt echt ein Rätsel.

Comment: "hin-" und "her-" scheinen mir auch vertauscht.

Comment: @Mac - Ich wollte eigentlich berücksichtigen, dass man über dritte reden kann: "Er soll zu ihr auffi" - das Ziel des Sprechakts befindet sich dann mit der angesprochenen auf einer Ebene, "er" dagegen darunter.

Comment: lol, ich glaube, wir reden aneinander vorbei: die Erklärungen zu "hin" und "her" sind vertauscht... Es müsste so heißen: hin = vom Sprecher weg, her = zum Sprecher hin.... darum ist auch die erste Person als Beispiel für "-a" nicht so günstig... den Spezialfall mit "ihr" würde ich nicht extra erwähnen, er folgt dem gleichen Muster: weg vom Sprecher :)

Comment: @Mac: du hast natürlich recht. §$/& Änderungen von Sprecher zu Beobachter.

Comment: Betreffend Oberbairisch: Ich hab nicht viel Ahnung von den Dialekten im Freistaat, aber mein Eindruck ist, dass *naus* und *raus* (mit einem schön gerollten *r*) typisch Fränkisch sind. (Geographisch betrachtet nicht so überraschend, dass das Fränkische näher am Hochdeutschen ist.) Von daher würde ich das primär als ein Phänomen der bairisch-fränkischen Übergangszone ansehen, wenn auch evt. durch das Hochdeutsche unterstützt.

Answer (score 7):

Vielleicht noch einige Ergänzungen zu splattnes und Joachims Antworten:

Das "i" ist 'breiter als im Hochdeutschen, es geht eher in Richtung "e".
Das "b" ist (typisch bayrisch/österreichisch) eine Mischung aus "b" und "w".

Die Ableitungen sind tatsächlich sehr regelmäßig. Für Auswärtige vielleicht nicht sofort ersichtlich ist, dass **obi** von **hinab**  kommt :)

Die hochdeutschen Präfixe werden im Bayrischen zu Suffixen:

aufi - hinauf

> "geh aufi" - "geh hinauf"

aufa - herauf

> "geh aufa" - "komm herauf"

obi - hinab

> "geh obi" - "geh hinunter"

oba - herauf

> "geh oba" - "komm herunter"

Also tatsächlich sehr logisch:
Endung "-i" = "hin-": von hier nach dort
Endung "-a" = "her-": von dort nach hier

Analog:

"umi" = hinüber, "uma" = herüber 
"zuawi" = zu etwas hin, "zuawa" = zu mir/uns her
"fieri" = nach vorne (Sprecher ist nicht vorne), "fiera" = nach vorne (Sprecher ist vorne)

(sorry, "dauni" ist mir nicht geläufig, scheint aber aus dem Muster "aussa" (heraus) zu fallen :))

Comment: "dauni" = "dort hin"

Answer (score 5):

Die dialektale Präposition *aufi*, die in bayerischen und österreichischen Dialekten verwendet wird, bedeutet auf Hochdeutsch *"hinauf"* - oder kurz: *"rauf"*.

> Mia miassn aufn Berg aufi kraxln.
>   *Wir müssen auf den Berg hinauf klettern.*

*obi* bedeutet *"hinunter"* / *"runter"*:

> Zum Glück bin i ned obi gfalln.
>   *Zum Glück bin ich nicht hinunter gefallen.*

Comment: Zwar völlig richtig, aber evt. etwas verwirrend: *rauf* und *runter* passen nur deshalb, weil sie heute meistens an die Stelle von *nauf* und *nunter* treten. Sie stehen hier also nicht für *herauf* und *herunter* sondern nur für die genannten *hinauf* und *hinunter*.

Answer (score 0):

Es sind die mittelbairisch lautgesetzlichen Aussprachevarietäten von "aufhin", "abhin", "hinterhin", "fürhin",... . Warum die Schriftsprache die Silbenreihenfolge vertauscht ist mir allerdings nicht klar.

Comment: Diese Antwort scheint mir nichts zu den existierenden hinzuzufügen. Kannst Du sie bitte ausbauen, sodass sie dies tut, oder löschen?